.NET Framework 4.8 - return content on OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext) error 406
I did store the resp on OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext) in CacheManagerService, but when I want to use it in OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext), it will return a http 406 or http 500 with no description.
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace ***.Mvc.ActionFilters
{
    public class SampleAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override async void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);

            var respCache = GetCache(key);

            if (respCache != null)
            {
                actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, await resp.ReadAsAsync(typeof(object)));
            }
        }

        public override async void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
        {
            base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
            SetCache(key,actionExecutedContext.Response.Content);
        }
    }
}

Note: it does work with Task<someClass> resp, but the problem is showing when I am using it on Task<IHttpActionResult> ODataController
Does anyone know how to fix this?

With the help of my friend, we found a solution for this.
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace ***.Mvc.ActionFilters
{
    public class SampleAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override async void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);

            var respCache = GetCache(key);

            if (respCache != null)
            {
                **var resp = (HttpContent)respCache;
                var value = await resp.ReadAsAsync(typeof(object));
                HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                response.Content = new ObjectContent(value.GetType(), value, GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter);
                actionContext.Response = response;**
            }
        }

        public override async void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
        {
            base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
            SetCache(key,actionExecutedContext.Response.Content);
        }
    }
}


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
